# Dudas de consultas de base de datos MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los equipos estan relacionadas a otra tabla llamada equipos. Que contiene: nombre(clave primaria),estadio,ciudad y fundación.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Con estas dos tablas me gustaría sacar una clasificación de los equipos con sus puntos.ejemplo: real madrid 20, atletico 19.

Averiguandolo con los goles locales y visitantes. Ejemplo si goles locas > goles visitantes ; Equipo Local tiene 3 puntos.

Comment: Añade la consulta que has intentado, para que te ayudemos a resolverlo.

Comment: Hola Borja. Tristemente, la pregunta no es clara. 1) Con tu última edición, creo que se perdió la información en cuanto a la tabla `equipos`. 2) Por favor, favorece usar texto mas bien que imágenes para que podamos copiar y hacer pruebas por nuestra cuenta. 3) Explica la *lógica* del resultado esperado. Decir *"me gustaria sacar la clasificación con puntos con la primera tabla"*, no se explica por sí solo. 4) Danos un ejemplo concreto del resultado esperado.

Comment: ¿Tiene sentido responder a una pregunta si el OP está por decirlo de alguna manera _desparecido_ desde diciembre? :) Si el OP aparece quizá se podría intentar una respuesta, pero en lo que a mi respecta la daría si el OP se muestra dispuesto a cambiar la estructura de sus tablas. Por ejemplo **¿por qué en la tabla de arriba tiene que repetirse una y otra vez el nombre del equipo?** Esa tabla va a **engordar** con el tiempo, mientras más partidos haya. Los números existen para algo ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes intentar esto, para sumar los puntos que obtiene cada equipo de local como visitante:

```
 SELECT 
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
    Equipo,sum(puntos) as puntos FROM (
        select Equipo_local as Equipo,
        sum(CASE WHEN Goles_local>Goles_visitante then 3 WHEN Goles_local=Goles_visitante then 1 else 0 END) as puntos
        from equipo
        Group by Equipo_local
        UNION
        SELECT Equipo_visitante as Equipo,
        sum(CASE WHEN Goles_local<Goles_visitante then 3 WHEN Goles_local=Goles_visitante then 1 else 0 END) as puntos
        from equipo
        Group by Equipo_visitante) t,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r
 group by t.Equipo
```

Comment: la modifique para agregarle la columna rank.

Comment: muchas gracias ahora lo probaré

Comment: buenísimo, cualquier duda que tengas no dudes en consultar.